Enter variable within a string found in the applitcation.properties
Good afternoon.
I am currently working with quarkus and apache camel and I need to return a controlled error for the different http codes, in the case of 404 I need to return the following message that I have configured as a variable in the application.properties:

Basically my service receives a mobile number as an input parameter and what I want to do is where the value of %1 is, that is, if I pass the number 5842410000 and it does not exist, return an error like the following:
Resource 5842410000 does not exist

I know that I can get the value of the properties in my mappign class as follows:
private final String exceptionText = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("error.404.exceptionText", String.class);

The issue is how can I make it dynamic to insert the value of the input field into the error message

You can have the %s placeholder in your application.properties file
error.404.exceptionText=Resource %s does not exist

And you can dynamically format the exceptionText with phone.
private final String exceptionText = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("error.404.exceptionText", String.class);

...

String dynamicExceptionText = String.format(exceptionText, phoneNumber);

Now %s placeholder will have phoneNumber value.
